# WPF Color interpolation

Tags: wpf, colors

I am trying to paint a WPF control's background based on a palette where each color has been assigned with values (e.g. Red = 0, DarkGreen = 10, Green = 20,LightGreen =30) and a user-selected value (e.g. 25) that would give the resulting color. I would like the resulting color to be an interpolation between the 2 nearest color values (e.g. for a value of 25 it should give a color between Green and LightGreen)

For that I'm thinking of using the existing LinearGradientBrush in WPF; set the GradientStops, offsets and get the color at a specified value . Is there a way to do this or should I implement my own color interpolation function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Using the LinearGradientBrush sounds like it would have a bit of an overhead. No knowledge though. A color interpolation function isn't that hard to write though.

I'm assuming your palettes have values that are divisible by 10 for simplicity.

```
public static Color GetColor(int value)
{
    int startIndex = (value/10)*10;
    int endIndex = startIndex + 10;

    Color startColor = Palette[startIndex];
    Color endColor = Palette[endIndex];

    float weight = (value - startIndex)/(float)(endIndex - startIndex);

    return Color.FromArgb(
        (int)Math.Round(startColor.R * (1 - weight) + endColor.R * weight),
        (int)Math.Round(startColor.G * (1 - weight) + endColor.G * weight),
        (int)Math.Round(startColor.B * (1 - weight) + endColor.B * weight));

}
```

If the defined colors are not divisible by 10 the logic to find the start and end colors will be a bit more complex.

Comment: for the record : either add 255 as the first argument of Color.FromArgb, or use Color.FromRgb. Thx for the post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this was the case back then but in .NET 4.0 getting a color from a LinearGradientBrush can be done.

```
private Color GetColor(double ratio)
{
    if (ratio < 0) ratio = 0;
    else if (ratio > 1) ratio = 1;

    //Find gradient stops that surround the input value
    GradientStop gs0 = ColorScale.GradientStops.Where(n => n.Offset <= ratio).OrderBy(n => n.Offset).Last();
    GradientStop gs1 = ColorScale.GradientStops.Where(n => n.Offset >= ratio).OrderBy(n => n.Offset).First();

    float y = 0f;
    if (gs0.Offset != gs1.Offset)
    {
        y = (float)((ratio - gs0.Offset) / (gs1.Offset - gs0.Offset));
    }

    //Interpolate color channels
    Color cx = new Color();
    if (ColorScale.ColorInterpolationMode == ColorInterpolationMode.ScRgbLinearInterpolation)
    {
        float aVal = (gs1.Color.ScA - gs0.Color.ScA) * y + gs0.Color.ScA;
        float rVal = (gs1.Color.ScR - gs0.Color.ScR) * y + gs0.Color.ScR;
        float gVal = (gs1.Color.ScG - gs0.Color.ScG) * y + gs0.Color.ScG;
        float bVal = (gs1.Color.ScB - gs0.Color.ScB) * y + gs0.Color.ScB;
        cx = Color.FromScRgb(aVal, rVal, gVal, bVal);
    }
    else
    {
        byte aVal = (byte)((gs1.Color.A - gs0.Color.A) * y + gs0.Color.A);
        byte rVal = (byte)((gs1.Color.R - gs0.Color.R) * y + gs0.Color.R);
        byte gVal = (byte)((gs1.Color.G - gs0.Color.G) * y + gs0.Color.G);
        byte bVal = (byte)((gs1.Color.B - gs0.Color.B) * y + gs0.Color.B);
        cx = Color.FromArgb(aVal, rVal, gVal, bVal);
    }
    return cx;
}
```

This would work with a brush configured as follows (for example):

```
var brush = new LinearGradientBrush();
brush.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
brush.EndPoint = new Point(1, 0);

//Set brush colors
brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromRgb(102, 40, 0), Offset = 0 });
brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromRgb(254, 167, 80), Offset = 0.25 });
brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 153, 51), Offset = 0.5 });
brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromRgb(232, 165, 255), Offset = 0.75 });
brush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromRgb(66, 0, 89), Offset = 1 });
```

Source:
http://dotupdate.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/find-the-color-of-a-point-in-a-lineargradientbrush/

Answer (score 1):

Where did you come up with the Values 10/20/30 for your DarkGreen/Green/Lightgreen colors.

You'll need some sort of correlation table between your assigned palette values & the real numeric representations of the colors... e.g.

```
Color             Pal-Code     RGB            HSL
Red               0            255,0,0        0,240,120
Dark Green        10           0,128,0        80,240,60
Green             20           0,255,0        80,240,120
Light Green       30           128,255,128    80,240,180
```

From that correlation table, you could take any user "palette code", find the closed matching pair of palette codes from the table above and do a best-match range find on it. e.g. if some entered `25` (let's use HSL for convenience) then the formula would be...

```
Green             20           0,255,0        80,240,120
Light Green       30           128,255,128    80,240,180
```

25 is halfway between both codes so

```
Palette Code     Hue        Sat      Luminence
20               80         240      120
30               80         240      180
-------------------------------------------------
25               80         240      150
```

If they had selected `6`, you'd need to find .6 of the range of colors between each value.

```
Red               0            255,0,0        0,240,120
Dark Green        10           0,128,0        80,240,60

Palette Code     Hue        Sat      Luminence
0                0          240      120
10               80         240      60
-------------------------------------------------
6                48         240      84

0->80      = +80 * 60%   = +48    So 0+48   = 48
240->240   =   0 * 60%   = 0      So 240+0  = 240
120->60    = -60 * 60%   = -36    So 120-36 = 84
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be better of using a value converter, just take one of the interpolation functions suggested in the other answers and put in in a value converter, use this converter to bind the background property to the value and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies guys. It seems there is no way to get the "value" of a GradientBrush at a specified point. I hope this is corrected at some later version of the framework. So I guess the only option for now is to implement an interpolation algorithm as Mikko suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is if you work with hue, saturation and brilliance of a color. You can convert and RGB color to their HSB values using a method like this:

```
public static (int Hue, double Saturation, double Brightness)GetHSB(this Color color) {
  int max = Math.Max(color.R, Math.Max(color.G, color.B));
  int min = Math.Min(color.R, Math.Min(color.G, color.B));
  int hue = 0;//for black, gray or white, hue could be actually any number, but usually 0 is 
              //assign, which means red
  if (max-min!=0) {
    //not black, gray or white
    int maxMinDif = max-min;
    if (max==color.R) {
      #pragma warning disable IDE0045 // Convert to conditional expression
      if (color.G>=color.B) {
      #pragma warning restore IDE0045
        hue = 60 * (color.G-color.B)/maxMinDif;
      } else {
        hue = 60 * (color.G-color.B)/maxMinDif + 360;
      }
    } else if (max==color.G) {
      hue = 60 * (color.B-color.R)/maxMinDif + 120;
    } else if(max == color.B) {
      hue = 60 * (color.R-color.G)/maxMinDif + 240;
    }
  }

  double saturation = (max == 0) ? 0.0 : (1.0-((double)min/(double)max));

  return (hue, saturation, (double)max/0xFF);
}
```

The hue defines the color, like red or blue from 0 to 360 degrees. If you want a gradient between blue (240 degrees) and red (360 degrees), you divide the 120 degrees by the number of steps and convert it back to RGB. But this is a bit complicated. Easier is just to mix the 2 colors using different weights:

```
/// <summary>
/// Mixes factor*color1 with (1-factor)*color2.
/// </summary>
public static Color Mix(this Color color1, double factor, Color color2) {
  if (factor<0) throw new Exception($"Factor {factor} must be greater equal 0.");
  if (factor>1) throw new Exception($"Factor {factor} must be smaller equal 1.");

  if (factor==0) return color2;
  if (factor==1) return color1;

  var factor1 = 1 - factor;
  return Color.FromArgb(
    (byte)((color1.A * factor + color2.A * factor1)),
    (byte)((color1.R * factor + color2.R * factor1)),
    (byte)((color1.G * factor + color2.G * factor1)),
    (byte)((color1.B * factor + color2.B * factor1)));
}
```

I wrote a long article on CodeProject about precisely this topic: [Definitive Guide to WPF Colors, Color Spaces, Color Pickers and Creating Your Own Colors for Mere Mortals](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5296124/Definitive-Guide-to-WPF-Colors-Color-Spaces-Color)