# How to Create a Duotone Interpolation Color in GDI+ (.NET)?

Tags: .net, colors, gdi+, linear-interpolation

I have two colors that I need to linearly interpolate to create a duotone color based of another color's luminance value.

```
Dim clr1 = Color.Black
Dim clr2 = Color.FromArgb(224, 255, 165)
Dim lum = Color.FromArgb(226, 189, 136).GetBrightness
'lum = 0.71
```

I know the result of this should be R=171, G=192, B=125, but I can't figure out how to do this. I've searched through [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790699/wpf-color-interpolation) quite a [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236683/color-interpolation-between-3-colors-in-net) and all over Google, but have not discovered a way to produce this result. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - my `lum` value should have been using [relative luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_(relative)) instead.