# How to interpolate between colors for a polygon in Bing Maps

Tags: wpf, colors, bing-maps, polygon, interpolation

I have a WPF application with the Bing Maps API. What I have is a polygon rendering on many countries as well as real time statistics being display. I'm using this to keep track of where my server traffic is mainly coming from. The project is coming along nicely, but I hit a small roadblock. What I have are polygons that go from green to red and vice versa if there is a change in the statistics. If someone logs off then it would go into the green, if someone logged on it would go into the red. What I'd like to do is given a set number of users, let's say 20, I can gradually change the colors over a period of a second.

An example is 0 would be green and 20 would be red. So 10 would be yellow. With this, is there a way to gradually change colors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was trying to figure out the same thing.  I ended up writing a slope function (y=mx+b) across a gradient map. I then plug the numbers into the Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(const, Y , MX , B).  Not incredibly impressed with the results so I'm looking for something better.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a fancy way of doing what you are looking for in xaml, but I imagine it would be a lot easier to to just have the color of the polygon bound to a property in your viewmodel/code-behind and then update the color whenever necessary.

For color interpolation, there is another SO question on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790699/wpf-color-interpolation).